# Filtering using queryset in django with the attribute in a given set

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

```
qs  = super(UserAdmin, self).queryset(request)
current_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
followers = UserProfile.objects.filter(lead_user=current_user)
return qs.filter(????)
```

qs is my queryset and

I want to literally return this

```
qs.filter(if lead_user is in followers ,add this else exclude )
```

Comment: who is `lead_user`  user here ? Also, `current_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)` is redundant - You can just do `current_user = request.user`

Comment: @karthikr lead_user is an attribute of UserAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)

```
qs = qs.filter(user__in=followers)
```

Basically, filter only the `UserAdmin` objects that are in `followers`

(replace `user__` with the appropriate field)